# Symfony Command Line Parse Error

Tags: php, symfony, parsing, command-line

Good afternoon,

I'm working on a symfony project and everything was going well until I received the following messages :

> PHP Warning:  Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in .../vendor/ocramius/proxy-manager/src/ProxyManager/Configuration.php on line 19
>
> PHP Parse error:  parse error, expecting `';'' or` '{'' in .../vendor/ocramius/proxy-manager/src/ProxyManager/Configuration.php on line 97

These 2 messages appear whenever I try to use the command line in symfony.

I tried the following commands:

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:entity
```

and

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod.
```

I also tried to use `php bin/console` instead of `app/console` as I'm aware the new symfony versions use `php bin/console`.

I'm using Mamp with php version 7.1 and Symfony version 2.8 for the projects.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `strict_types` for `declare` added in php7. Make sure your php version is 7.

Comment: yes my php version is 7.1.1. When I try to use the commands in another symfony project I have, it works fine. Only this projects seems to have issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone runs into this issue it means that your php version is not 7.0 The issue I had was that the Mamp version was 7.1.1 and the symfony project was also running on 7.1.1 in the browser but when I checked the php version in the bash commands, it was 5.6 so make sure you're bash commands use php 7.0 instead of 5.6

Comment: hi, if I want to resolve this issue on php 7 below versions ?